# pdo insert multiple rows with foreach

Tags: pdo, foreach, preg-match-all

I know this question has already been answered but i doesn't really get the solution of my problem. I actualy try to insert of many parts

Here is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => blablablablablabl        
            [1] => Jo Byung Gyu
            [2] => https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT5ynS8xnQneaIWFdHzy8A11dwG57pZHwAXh2OCDVaOfLMYyE354Y9NMhsDkx7IeFAduMx8Q_uIhiburan 
            [3] => http://www.tribunnews.com/section/2019/02/21/pemeran-sky-castle-jo-byung-gyu-dan-kim-bo-ra-resmi-berpacaran-intip-momen-mereka-saat-berkencan
        )
```

i use php 7.2 and already try _https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp but stuck how to fix it?

i want insert 3 of array multiple array 1-3

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve. Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54805033/edit) and add what you've tried, what you get and what is your expected result.

Comment: @Toto im not american or british, my english poor, u can edit post to make correction if u want. dont make stranger think same as u. understand ? i learn english by gugel

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $initial_array  as $arr){
   foreach ( $arr as $second_arr){
         here you put your mysql multi insert

   }
}
```

Iterate 2 foreach if is a 2 dimensional array

Comment: seems interesting, let me try, or could u give me example full coding with insert pdo also ?